# Search in a column from a record from another dataset Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a dataset of 46 distinct country names. I have another dataset where country is one of the columns. I want to find extra countries which do not belong to those 46 countries. I want to do it using DAX function but no idea how to proceed further. I am novice to Power BI and look for your suggestion.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Do these 46 distinct countries reside in a single column in a source table? In absence of a sample data, the way I understand this (and please correct me if I am wrong), it would be easier to achieve this with Power Query given the structure of the source data I imagined

```
/*_dim*/

let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WCg1WitUBUt5gytnRTyk2FgA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Country = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Country", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
    
/*_fact*/
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUXIEEU4gwhlEuBgqxcYCAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [SN = _t, US = _t, UK = _t, CAN = _t, AUS = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"SN", Int64.Type}, {"US", type text}, {"UK", type text}, {"CAN", type text}, {"AUS", type text}}),
    Custom1 = Table.DemoteHeaders(#"Changed Type"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Custom1,{{"Column1", type any}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}, {"Column4", type text}, {"Column5", type text}}),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Changed Type1"),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Transposed Table", {"Column1"}, _dim, {"Country"}, "_dim", JoinKind.LeftAnti),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Merged Queries",{"_dim"}),
    #"Transposed Table1" = Table.Transpose(#"Removed Columns"),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table1", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"SN", Int64.Type}, {"AUS", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type2"
```